# "TypeError: response.json is not a function" when trying to parse json

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am getting an error I do not understand. I'm fetching an API url in json format, followed by a json to JS object parsing, using json()

```
const response = fetch('https://power.larc.nasa.gov/api/temporal/monthly/point?parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DNI&community=RE&longitude=48.0000&latitude=27.0000&format=JSON&start=2001&end=2020');

const data = response.json();
```

Can someone please explain this error..

Comment: [Fetch API | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), [Using Fetch | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: you forgot to `await` before the `fetch` so you're trying to call `.json()` on a promise

Comment: I have tried await in front of fetch. Does not work.

Comment: @Andreas I have read the Fetch API docs but obviously I have missed something.

Comment: _"... Does not work"_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**`fetch` is an asynchronous function**; it doesn't return the response right away (you get a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead).

If you want to fetch the data, you need to use the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) (if the fetch is called inside another [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)), or [provide a callback via `then` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) in the `Promise` from the `fetch` call:

```js
fetch('https://power.larc.nasa.gov/api/temporal/monthly/point?parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DNI&community=RE&longitude=48.0000&latitude=27.0000&format=JSON&start=2001&end=2020')
.then(response => {
   const data = response.json();
});
```

### Working with data from response

If you would do something like this, it won't work:

```js
let data;

fetch('https://power.larc.nasa.gov/api/temporal/monthly/point?parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DNI&community=RE&longitude=48.0000&latitude=27.0000&format=JSON&start=2001&end=2020')
.then(response => {
   data = response.json();
});

console.log(data);
```

The reason is because the callback inside the `then` method **is executed after the response has been returned** (this might take seconds for example), but **the `console.log(data)` is executed immediately after the `fetch` is called**. This means that the data isn't assigned yet and will be probably `undefined`. For this reason, if you want to put `data` somewhere, you need to **put your code inside the callback**.

```js
function processData(responseData) {
    // Here, you can put your code to process the data from response
    console.log(responseData);
}

fetch('https://power.larc.nasa.gov/api/temporal/monthly/point?parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DNI&community=RE&longitude=48.0000&latitude=27.0000&format=JSON&start=2001&end=2020')
.then(response => {
    const data = response.json();

    processData(data);
});
```

This way the `data` will be processed *after* it is fetched.

Comment: Thanks @bobkorinek. When trying this I get ReferenceError: data is not defined. I also tried defining the data constant before fetch, but does not work.

Comment: Is there some kind of return statement I need to add inside the then method?

Comment: No, there is not return value from the `fetch` function right away. I've tried to create an example how to get this data via `then` callback *and* process it afterwards in this answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: I can see your edits @bobkorintek. Will do some experimenting.

Answer (score -1):

Fetch returns a Promise since you are sending a request to an API. This type of functions is `asynchronous` since we don't know when we're getting back the response from the API.

You can either use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or [.then() and .catch()](https://lucymarmitchell.medium.com/using-then-catch-finally-to-handle-errors-in-javascript-promises-6de92bce3afc) to execute your code when you get back the response.

Try this:

```
let returnedData;
fetch('https://power.larc.nasa.gov/api/temporal/monthly/point?parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DNI&community=RE&longitude=48.0000&latitude=27.0000&format=JSON&start=2001&end=2020')
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    returnedData = data
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```